# Deleting folder on my OS X 10.10.5 by executing a file

Tags: osx-yosemite, directory

I have a list of files I want to delete on my mac, how do I automate this without entering each into the terminal with a

"sudo rm -r folderName"

Here is the list of folders:

```
/Library/Application Support/VMware
/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion
/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion
~/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion
~/Library/Caches/com.vmware.fusion
~/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion
~/Library/Preferences/com.vmware.fusion.LSSharedFileList.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.vmware.fusion.LSSharedFileList.plist.lockfile
~/Library/Preferences/com.vmware.fusion.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.vmware.fusion.plist.lockfile
~/Library/Preferences/com.vmware.fusionDaemon.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.vmware.fusionDaemon.plist.lockfile
~/Library/Preferences/com.vmware.fusionStartMenu.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.vmware.fusionStartMenu.plist.lockfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this in your terminal to remove the files you list and recursively clear out directories in your list.

`while read p; do rm -r $p; done <list.txt`

list.txt is a list of files/directories with each entry on its own line.

This will loop over that list and call `rm -r` with the file/directory name.